# How can I insert data from a table from sql into a dropdown list in zend framework 2?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

I need to insert multioptions to a dropdown list, options taken from a table from my database. 
I created the elements like:

```
    $this->add(array(
        'name'       => 'company',
        'type'       => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        //'multiOptions'=> $options,
        'options'    => array(
            'label'        => 'Company',
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'style'  => "float:right;",
        ),          
    ));
```

I want to choose from a dropdown list some values that are in a table in my database. For example I have the entity Contacts and I need to choose for the contact a company that is in a table named companies in the database.

After reading on zend framework's site, I tried using this code:

```
$params = array(
           'driver'=>'Pdo_Mysql',
           'host'=>'localhost',
           'username'=>'root',
           'password'=>'',
           'dbname'  =>'myDataBase'
            );

$db = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($params);
$sql= new Sql($db);

$select = $sql->select();
$select ->from('companies')
    ->columns(array('id','company_name'))
    ->order(" 'company_name' ASC");
```

I also read on some other sites that I could use a function:

```
$options = $sql->fetchPairs('SELECT id, name FROM country ORDER BY name ASC');
```

but it seems it doesn't exist anymore in Zend Framework 2.

Please guys, give me a hand. If the code isn't good and you have a better idea, please tell me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The array key for the dropDownList is `'value_options' => array()`, alternatively you can use `$element->setValueOptions(array())`

Comment: well it doesn't help me to much, who's that $element?how do I need to instantiate it?and how to add the database values in that array?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick and dirty answer, but i guess it can get you started.

1. Create a `ServiceFactory`, this should be done in a separate factory class instead of a closure, but i still use a closure - faster to write ;)
2. Get the config from the `ServiceLocator` so you have access to the DB-Params
3. Create your default SQL Stuff to retriefe the `value_options`
4. Populate the `value_options` using the `setValueOptions($valueOptions)` function of your given form-element

**Module.php `getServiceConfig()`**

```
return array(
    'factories' => array(
        'my-form-factory' => function($serviceLocator) {
            $form   = new My\Form();
            $config = $serviceLocator->get('config');
            $db     = new \Zend\Db\Auth\Adapter\Adapter($config['dbParams']); //or whatever you named the array key

            $sql    = //do your SQL Stuff
            // This is a fake array, it should be your $sql result in the given format
            $result = array('value' => 'label', 'value2' => 'label2'); 

            $form->get('elementToPopulate')->setValueOptions($result);
            return $form;
        }
    )
);
```

**SomeController.php `someAction()`**

```
$form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('my-form-factory');

return new ViewModel(array(
    'form' => $form
));
```

I hope this gets you started

Answer (score 0):

you have to add that field validation on controller for setting value in it.

```
$select = $db->select()->where("state_code = ?",$arr["state_code"]);
$resultSet = $cityObj->fetchAll($select);
$cityArr = $resultSet->toArray();

$city_ar = array();
foreach($cityArr as $city){
    $city_ar[$city['id']] = $city['company'];
}
$form->company->setMultiOptions($city_ar);
$form->company->setValue($val["company"]);
```

by using this code drop down of country have the value that are in resultset array (**$resultSet**).

Comment: sorry guys, this zend framework gives me headaches sometimes, so I solved the problem using classic php, creating an array in which I pushed all the values I needed, and after that I entered in the element's options 'value_options' => /*my created array*/ and it worked